# Join columns of the same data.frame

Tags: r

How to join 2 columns from a single `data.frame`

For example:

```
Column A : a,b,c,d,e
Column B : b,c,a,b,e
```

The column i want

```
New Column : a,b,c,d,e,b,c,a,b,e
```

Basically i want to get all data under both columns into a single column

Comment: `A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"); B <- c("b", "c", "a", "b", "e"); newC <- c(A, B)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(, nrow = 100, ncol = 2)), c("V1", "V2"))
df$V1 <- "a, b, c, d, e"
df$V2 <- "b, c, a, b, e"
df$V3 <- paste(df$V1, df$V2, sep = ", ")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R you could just copy the `data.frame` to a new object and concatenate the columns A and B using the `c()` function:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  B = c("b", "c", "a", "b", "e"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  AB = c(df$A, df$B)
)
```

Alternatively, you could use a *tidyverse* approach with the `gather()` function from the [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) package. This has the advantage that you can easily include the old column IDs (A or B) from the original `data.frame` in each row.

```
library(tidyr)
df_tidy <- df %>% 
  gather(key = "old_col_id", value = "value", A, B)
```